# How to clone JFrog Artifactory into a local installation of JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have JFrog Artifactory `http://organization.com/artifactory/` with read access. I can download individual artifacts let's say `gulp-git-2.8.0.tgz` using native browser.

Now, I have created local JFrog Artifactory `http://localhost.com:8081/artifactory/` in machine and it does not have any artifacts.

I am trying to fetch my organizations artifacts lets say of npm package `http://organization.com/artifactory/npm/` into my local artifactory `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/npm/`

Since it has many artifacts and I cannot do it manually of download from organization server and deploying it to my local server.

Is there anyway that I can fetch only the required package let's say `npm` to my local server? Or is there anyway to replicate my organization's package using read access into my local server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Admin permissions to the source Artifactory you can setup [Push replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PushReplication) or to perform a [Repository Export](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-Export).
Without Admin permissions, you can:

1. Setup [Pull Replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PullReplication).
2. Use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) in order to download entire repository content, and then upload it in the same structure.